# Не могу понять алгоритм вычисления

Tags: алгоритм, ассемблер, арифметика

```
movsx eax,byte ptr ds:[r9+2]                     
movsx ecx,byte ptr ds:[r9+3]                      
add r11d,1                                          
add ecx,eax                                         
movsx eax,byte ptr ds:[r9+1]                        
add rbx,4                                           
add ecx,eax                                         
movsx eax,byte ptr ds:[r9]                         
add r9,5                                            
 lea ecx,qword ptr ds:[rcx+rax-C0]                   
 mov dword ptr ds:[rbx-4],ecx                        
 add r10d,ecx
```

берется код 4 и 3 символа блока, складывается, потом добавляется код 2 символа, первого и всё это помещается в `ecx` командой `lea ecx,qword ptr ds:[rcx+rax-C0]`, только вот операция происходит не арифметическая а какая-то сдвиговая что ли, т.е. 30+30 - 5 (например) не равно 55.
Уже прочитал все что связанно с lea на coderoad, но так и не понял
можно ли по полкам разложить `lea ecx,qword ptr ds:[rcx+rax-C0]`?

Comment: Почему `30+30 - 5` должно быть равно 55? А чему равно? lea - именно арифметическая операция, без всяких сдвигов. Единственно при переполнении регистра ecx вся старшая часть (все что выше 32 бит) будет отброшена.

Comment: ну на конкретных данных, скажем так, При отладке, когда дохожу до lea команды, данные такие lea ecx,qword ptr ds:[90+30-192] , при ее выполнении ecx=0. Да, операция происходит между 64 и 32 регистрами, где об этом можно почитать? Спасибо

Comment: Вы в отладчике в регистрах видите числа в шестнадцатеричном виде, поэтому все правильно: 0x90 + 0x30 - 192 == 0. Никакой магии и сдвигов - просто не в той системе счисления считаете. Где еще почитать - там же где вы уже читали.

Comment: ну а вот еще пример lea ecx,qword ptr ds:[171+39-192] почему-то равно 24, хоть в какой системе! А вроде должно быть равно 8!

Comment: в консоли отладчика такая информация qword ptr ds:[rcx+rax*1-C0]=[FFFFFFFFFFFFFF98]=??? ...точно не переполнение или сдвиги?

Comment: FFFFFFFFFFFFFF98 - это -104 в дополнительном коде. Не переполнение, и не сдвиги, просто отрицательное значение. `ну а вот еще пример lea ecx,qword ptr ds:[171+39-192] почему-то равно 24, хоть в какой системе` - `171+0x39-192 = 0x24`. Все нормально, просто внимательно проверяйте, в какой системе у вас данные в отладчике выводятся.